# my app crashes ! need help ..there seems to be an error in the logcat

Tags: android, inflate-exception

```
05-10 19:09:13.744 17071-17071/com.example.personal.enco E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     Process: com.example.personal.enco, PID: 17071
     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.personal.enco/com.example.personal.enco.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.RelativeLayout
         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.RelativeLayout
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:288)
         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
         at com.example.personal.enco.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6259)
         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.RelativeLayout
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:288) 
         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
         at com.example.personal.enco.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12) 
         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6259) 
         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
      Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.constraint.RelativeLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.personal.enco-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.personal.enco-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.personal.enco-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.personal.enco-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.personal.enco-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.personal.enco-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.personal.enco-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.personal.enco-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.personal.enco-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.personal.enco-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.personal.enco-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.personal.enco-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.personal.enco-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.example.personal.enco-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.example.personal.enco-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.example.personal.enco-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.example.personal.enco-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.example.personal.enco-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.example.personal.enco-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.example.personal.enco-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.example.personal.enco-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.example.personal.enco-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.example.person
```

Comment: And have you tried searching on the internet before posting the question?

Answer (score 2):

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.RelativeLayout
```

You have a layout resource in which you have an XML element named `android.support.constraint.RelativeLayout`. There is no such class in Android. `RelativeLayout` can be referred to in your layouts simply as `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

can u post for which API u r developing the application?
have u done any updates ?? check your SDK packages,

or else

create one activity2.xml with one Linear Layout or Relative layout and apply for your activity by removing your old activity1.xml in u r setContentView ,and run the application ..

try this